# Why different error when using different network connection to put a file to a s3 bucket with Sign v4?

Tags: python-2.7, boto3

Here are my code:

First the driver script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from gen_url import sign
import requests
import uuid

def upload_me(file_path, key=None, secret=None):
    access_key = 'ABC' if key is None else key
    secret_key = 'EDF' if secret is None else secret
    s3_bucket = 'my-work-bucket'
    object_name = '1-2-{uuid}.jpeg'.format(uuid=uuid.uuid4())
    mime_type = 'image/jpeg'
    expires = 24 * 60 * 60 # link expiry in sec
    os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = access_key
    os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = secret_key
    region = 'us-west-2'
    url = sign(key, secret, s3_bucket, object_name, mime_type, expires, region)
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        resp = requests.post(url, data=f)
        print resp.content


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argc = len(sys.argv)
    key = secret = None
    if argc == 2 or argc == 4:
        file_path = sys.argv[1]
        if argc == 4:
            key = sys.argv[2]
            secret = sys.argv[3]
    else:
        raise Exception('Expect 1 or 3 arguments')
    upload_me(file_path, key, secret)
```

The code of `sign` function in `gen_url` module

```
import sys
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
from datetime import datetime, date, time

def sign(access_key, secret_key, s3_bucket, object_name, mime_type, expires, region):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             region_name=region,
                             aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                             aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

    # Don't include content type
    #    'ContentType': mime_type
    params = {
        'Bucket': s3_bucket,
        'Key': object_name,
        }

    response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                                Params=params,
                                                ExpiresIn=expires)

    return response
```

When I am using the internet connection at home, it is the error I got:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

But I use tethering with my iphone, the command gives a different error:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Why totally different output when the networks are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the last three lines of the driver script should be:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    resp = requests.put(url, data=f)
    print resp.content
```

Then there is no issue with either connections.

`(error(32, 'Broken pipe')` could be just a coincidence that there were connection issue with my ISP.